# Simple display of DICOM format file image

Tags: image, scheme, racket, dicom

I am trying to read a simple dicom file named "CR-MONO1-10-chest" from http://www.barre.nom.fr/medical/samples/ which is a 440x440 sized image.

As expained on http://www.dclunie.com/medical-image-faq/html/part1.html , the image data is at the end of the file:

> In other words, if an image is 256 by 256, uncompressed, and 12-16
>   bits deep (and hence usually, though not always, stored as two bytes
>   per pixel), then we all know that the file is going to contain
>   256*256*2=131072 bytes of pixel data at the end of the file. If the
>   file is say 145408 bytes long, as all GE Signa 3X/4X files are for
>   example, then you need to skip 14336 bytes of header before you get to
>   the data. Presume row by row starting with top left hand corner raster
>   order, try both alternatives for byte order, deal with the 16 to 8 bit
>   windowing problem, and very soon you have your image on the screen of
>   your workstation.

A figure on http://people.cas.sc.edu/rorden/dicom/index.html also shows that the image data is located at the end of the file.

I am using following code to read and display image in this file:

```
(define in (open-input-file "CR-MONO1-10-chest" #:mode 'binary))
(define size (* 2 440 440))                        ; width and ht are 440
(define ignore (read-bytes (- 387976 size) in))    ; size of file is 387976
(define imgdata (read-bytes size in))
(close-input-port in)

(define img (make-object bitmap% imgdata 440 440))
img
```

However, it only shows a random mix of black and white pixels:

[image]

Using 440*440 instead of 2*440*440 also does not work.

Following code also does not read the image:

```
(define img (make-object bitmap% in 'unknown))
```

This does not display any image at all.

Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the coding language you're using, but are you sure you are displaying the image as 16-bit?  That is, this is a single channel 16-bit image. Also note that in this image's header, it indicates that only 10 bits are used to store the data -- so you should be masking out the other 6 bits of each pixel -- if you ignore this it would probably still look OK since the extra bits are probably (but not guaranteed) to be zeros.

Comment: Racket does not natively support the DICOM image format, so you would have to decode it. Writing an entire decoder is outside the scope of Stack Overflow, so this question is too broad.

Comment: I am not trying to write entire decoder. I am just trying to display image data which is at the end of the file.

Comment: Do you just want to render this particular file or any DICOM file with your approach? If the latter is your goal: You have no chance to reach it without decoding and interpreting the header data. You problem is probably related to bit-depth (is your language/library capable of handling > 8 bpp bitmaps?) and/or endianess, garbage" in unused bits in the pixel data.

Comment: I am interested in the image in this file. What changes can I try in my code?

Comment: As Alexis said, you need to write a decoder for the image format. You may want to talk to the folks over at lambdanative (Google it) since they do medical software in Scheme (though they use Gambit Scheme). They  most likely have some ideas if they have not already written a DICOM decoder.

Comment: If you just want to see that image, I would recommend an easy to use tool that is capable of converting it to a format that is easier to handle. E.g. IrfanView or dcmtk - dcm2pnm

Comment: @mso Out of curiosity are you waiting to see if a better answer comes along before releasing the bounty?

Comment: Yes. Also I am not able to decide which of the 2 is the better answer since both are very good. Can the functions be made more generalized so that they may be used for other single-image dicom files also?

Comment: @mso Depending on how general you want it that could be a pretty big job, even for 50 rep :). I definitely think your best bet is to use dcmtk (dcmtk.org/dcmtk.php.en). It includes command-line utilities that can convert DICOM files to various image formats that Racket does support, so you can just call out to those utilities using Racket's `system` procedure and then grab the results. And dcmtk appears to be mature and cross-platform. I just downloaded and built it on my MacBook, then used dcm2pnm (with the +obr option) to get the image from the sample file with no problems.

Comment: What addition to the code will be needed if this was a multi-image rather than single image file (all other setting remaining the same)?

Comment: @mso Try the new code at the end of my answer.

Comment: @rnso Keep in mind that this solution works for the specific image you linked to, that's all.  The image dimensions as well as lots of other information is hardcoded.  To make this general, you'd need to start by building a DICOM header parser.  And from the header, then you could extract the info needed to decode the image data.  Doing this from scratch is a huge task.

Comment: @rnso If all you want to do is lay out the images in a grid pattern, then you'd just need to read them all in a loop and translate the frames into position.  This is more of a UI decision -- the code wouldn't really need to change very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the Racket drawing library does not recognize that image encoding. I suggest converting it to 32-bit ARGB:

```
(require racket/draw)

(define (dicom->bitmap path x y)
  (let* ([bmp            (make-object bitmap% x y)]
         [dc             (send bmp make-dc)]
         [dicom          (file->bytes path #:mode 'binary)]
         [header-size    (- (file-size path) (* 2 x y))]
         [dicom-img/raw  (subbytes dicom header-size)]
         [dicom-img/argb (dicom-img->argb dicom-img/raw)])
    (send dc set-argb-pixels 0 0 x y dicom-img/argb)
    (send dc get-bitmap)))

(define (dicom-img->argb bytes)
  (let* ([len         (bytes-length bytes)]
         [pixel-count (/ len 2)]
         [argb        (make-bytes (* 4 pixel-count))])
    (define (set-pixel! value ix)
      (let ([offset (* 4 ix)])
        (bytes-set! argb offset 0)
        (bytes-set! argb (+ 1 offset) value)
        (bytes-set! argb (+ 2 offset) value)
        (bytes-set! argb (+ 3 offset) value)))
    (for ([ix (in-range pixel-count)])
      (let* ([offset       (* 2 ix)]
             [pixel-value  (+ (bytes-ref bytes offset)
                              (arithmetic-shift (bytes-ref bytes (+ 1 offset)) 8))]
             [scaled-value (arithmetic-shift pixel-value -2)])
        (set-pixel! scaled-value ix)))
    argb))
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
(dicom->bitmap "CR-MONO1-10-chest" 440 440)
```

This particular program works only for 10 bits/pixel stored in 2 bytes each in little-endian order, but with modest effort you could parameterize it for other encodings.

If you have a file with multiple images in that format, all at the end, this program should be able to extract them as a list of bitmaps.

```
(require racket/draw)

(define (dicom->bitmap* path x y z)
  (let* ([dicom           (file->bytes path #:mode 'binary)]
         [img-size        (* 2 x y z)]
         [header-size     (- (file-size path) img-size)]
         [dicom-img/raw*  (for/list ([z^ (in-range z)])
                            (let* ([offset    (+ header-size (* z^ img-size))]
                                   [img-bytes (subbytes dicom offset (+ offset img-size))])
                              img-bytes))])
    (map (λ (raw) (raw->bitmap raw x y)) dicom-img/raw*)))

(define (raw->bitmap bytes x y)
  (let* ([bmp             (make-object bitmap% x y)]
         [drawing-context (send bmp make-dc)]
         [dicom-img/argb  (raw->argb bytes)])
    (send drawing-context set-argb-pixels 0 0 x y dicom-img/argb)
    (send drawing-context get-bitmap)))

(define (raw->argb bytes)
  (let* ([len         (bytes-length bytes)]
         [pixel-count (/ len 2)]
         [argb        (make-bytes (* 4 pixel-count))])
    (define (set-pixel! value ix)
      (let ([offset (* 4 ix)])
        (bytes-set! argb offset 0)
        (bytes-set! argb (+ 1 offset) value)
        (bytes-set! argb (+ 2 offset) value)
        (bytes-set! argb (+ 3 offset) value)))
    (for ([ix (in-range pixel-count)])
      (let* ([offset       (* 2 ix)]
             [pixel-value  (+ (bytes-ref bytes offset)
                              (arithmetic-shift (bytes-ref bytes (+ 1 offset)) 8))]
             [scaled-value (arithmetic-shift pixel-value -2)])
        (set-pixel! scaled-value ix)))
    argb))
```

Where z is the number of images. I've only been able to test it with z=1 though: `(dicom->bitmap* "CR-MONO1-10-chest" 440 440 1)`

Answer (score 3):

You are calculating the image data offset correctly and this data appears to be raw and uncompressed.  The problem appears to be just that Racket does not support this kind of image data.  This is 16-bit, single channel, intensity data.  Each two bytes represents a pixel in grayscale (and actually for this image only 10 bits is used, the other 6 bits should be ignored).

The `make-object` `make-bitmap` functions appear to support only color (24 or 32) or monochrome (1) bit depth.  This is what jumps out at you in your example: nowhere when you create the bitmap do you state the pixels are 16-bit.  Also absent is anything about byte order.  And nowhere in the Racket documentation does it appear that it allows you to specify either of these.

Lack of support for 16-bit grayscale data seems evident in the get-depth function [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/bitmap_.html):

> (send a-bitmap get-depth) → exact-nonnegative-integer? 
>   Gets the color depth of the bitmap, **which is 1 for a monochrome bitmap
>   and 32 for a color bitmap**. See also is-color?.

Here's one solution, looping through and converting each 16-bit pixel into an ARGB pixel.

```
#lang racket/gui
(define in (open-input-file "CR-MONO1-10-chest" #:mode 'binary))
(define size (* 2 440 440))                        ; width and ht are 440
(define ignore (read-bytes (- 387976 size) in))    ; size of file is 387976
(define imgdata (read-bytes size in))
(close-input-port in)

(define rgbdata (make-bytes (* 4 440 440)))
(define img (make-object bitmap% 440 440))

(define max 1024.0) ; 10 bits valid

(for ([y 440])
  (for ([x 440])
      (define index (+ (* y 440) x))
      (define b1 (bytes-ref imgdata (+ (* index 2) 0))) ; first byte
      (define b2 (arithmetic-shift (bytes-ref imgdata (+ (* index 2) 1)) 8)) ; second byte
      (define val (bitwise-xor b1 b2)) ; combine bytes
      (define screenval (exact-floor (* 255 (/ val max)))) ; convert to 8-bit screen value

      ; create ARGB pixel
      (define b (bytes (bytes-ref (make-bytes 1 255) 0) (bytes-ref (make-bytes 1 screenval) 0) (bytes-ref (make-bytes 1 screenval) 0) (bytes-ref (make-bytes 1 screenval) 0)))    
      (send img set-argb-pixels x y 1 1 b)
  ))

img
```

Producing:

[image]

A note of caution though: be aware that there are many, many ways image data can be stored in DICOM files (some good examples on the page you linked).  And there are many parts of the DICOM header you would need to pay attention to decode the image data correctly.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. I dumped initial bytes from this file and found that the sequence "DICM" is not present at 128 bytes offset. That I thought was usual indication of a dicom file, although clearly it will not be essential. ("DICM" after initial 128 bytes is present in others files on that webpage).

Comment: @rnso DICM at byte 128 is the way to identify a DICOM file.  That file is an outlier.  It's missing the preamble and meta file information block.  Extremely uncommon to not find DICM at byte 128.